# DBT - Merge - Only update condition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Hi i'm currently working on a dbt solution that is using 2 sources that has to merge to a destination table, i'm using

```
{{
    config(
      unique_key = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
      merge_exclude_columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
    )
}}
```

The thing is that i need to use other two tables to only update some rows (that match on this 3 columns (col1, col2 and col3)). I don't need to use a standard merge that inserts and updates the rows when the join is made but only update the rows when this matches,

How could i make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need the `LEFT JOIN` operation, not the `incremental` dbt models. `merge_exclude_columns` is used for `materialized='incremental'` models, not views or tables.

I guess you need a dbt model like this:

```sql
{{
    config(
      materialized='table'
    )
}}

SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM {{ source('source', 'table_1') }} a
LEFT JOIN {{ source('source', 'table_2') }} b
  ON
    b.col1 = a.col1
    b.col2 = a.col2
    b.col3 = a.col3
```

dbt will recreate this table from scratch on every run.

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the response, i already had a model name final_table.sql, this one is incremental and had a merge condition in which 3 tables merge the data to this final_table in snowflake. Additionally i need another model or something like this, maybe a macro, idk, that only updates information in this final table

Comment: Hey Robertino, in this case I believe you need to either incorporate left join to the final_table.sql model code to update fields, or create a separate model which will (1) reference final_table, (2) update fields and (3) create a new table in your Snowflake. I don't think there is a way in dbt to update the table outside of the model definition. So if you want to have operations performed on the `final_table` you need to have them inside the `final_table.sql` model.

Comment: Also, please note that dbt incremental models do not merge several tables into one. They merge new `final_table` rows into the existing `final_table`. In other words, an incremental model merges `final_table` into itself, not other tables into the `final_table`.

Comment: Till now i've something like this: final_table.sql model has an IF condition, that uses 1 of the 3 input sources so makes the merge only for 1 on the 3 options, i don't know if that makes sense, and after that i have another model in other folder that have the same name final_table.sql, this model is only executed after this "complementary" tables are loaded, and makes another merge, but i want to updated final_table just for a couple of columns not all, and theres where i thinks is the problem, maybe with a set query = 'UPDATE...',  do run_query (query) inside this second final_table model

Comment: Another question dude, i want to have a single final_table.sql model in which i want to load data from different source models. I defined as incremental dis final_table.sql and put this on the top: -- depends_on: {{ ref('model1') }}
-- depends_on: {{ ref('model2') }}
-- depends_on: {{ ref('model3') }} I don't know if that makes any sense, but after this i punt something like {% if{{ ref('model1') }} == 'true' %} ... do something, elif ... do something else with model2, etc. This can be achievable?